# How can I check in javascript if it's day time or night time on the client?

Tags: javascript, date, date-nfs

Using [`date-nfs`](https://date-fns.org/v2.9.0/docs/isBefore), how can I check if `new Date()` is between 8am and 8pm?

Comment: Please at least [attempt to try to solve the issue on your own](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Comment: `nighttime = new Date(); nightTime.setHours(20, 0, 0); isBefore(new Date(), nighttime)`? You've linked to the correct doc already, so what's the problem?

Comment: The title and the content of your question are a bit misleading? Are you trying to determine whether it's 8pm or 8am (day time or night time as the title indicates), or are you trying to determine if the current time is between the hours of 8am and 8pm (as the question text indicates)?

Comment: var result = format(new Date(2014, 6, 2, 15), "h") ;
if(result > 8 && result < 20) {//do your stuff}

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use external libraries, you can simply get the current hour by `new Date().getHours()`, and check if it's more then 20 or less then 8.

Answer (score 0):

`getHours()` on the date object will be an integer between 0 and 23. So you could check if it's between 8 and 20